# INSERT INTO statement with connection to other table

Tags: sql-server

I am learning `INSERT INTO` statement in SQL Server and I have this problem where I added a new instructor to the `Instructors` table (which I've done right) and now I need to insert a record indicating that the new instructor is teaching the new course that I need to insert. I am using ClassTrak DB here. Anybody knows how to make this possible?

Comment: You haven't posted any table definitions so it's anyones guess... so my guess is that when you inserted the Instructors record it generated an ID - you need to `SELECT * FROM Instructors` to check this. Then you just need a new insert statement that inserts this ID and whatever info is needed into the table

Comment: yes it did generate an ID, thank you. It did work.

Comment: I can't tell based on the above conversation. Is this resolved? You good?